# How to Resolve the Error of maximum memory exceeds

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, lifecycle, application-lifecycle

I got that Memory Exceed error in my Vue typescript Code

```
public async created() {
  if (this.item) {
    await this.loadAppointments();
  }
}

private async loadAppointments(_items?: Appointments) {
  const _item: AppointmentsDetails = await LicenseSubscriptionAPI.getInstance().getAppointments();
  // console.log(_item.app)
  this.item =_item.app;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the Updated and Remove the async await call from Created Hook where we call the `LoadAppointments()` function

```js
public created() {
this.loadAppointments();
}
```